# How to add to default context menu in Python textbox using PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to add a functionality to a text box where a user can highlight a word, right click and be able to choose whether to define or get synonyms for the highlighted word. I coded a context menu but it only appears when I click outside of the textbox. Is there anyway I can add functions to the default context menu that includes Copy, Paste, etc.? Here is my code for the context menu.

```
self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
defineAction = QtWidgets.QAction("Define", self)
defineAction.triggered.connect(lambda: self.define(event))
self.addAction(defineAction)
synonymAction = QtWidgets.QAction("Find Synonyms", self)
synonymAction.triggered.connect(lambda: self.synonym(event))
self.addAction(synonymAction)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to subclass the text edit widget and override `createStandardContextMenu(point)`.

In your overridden method, cal the base call implementation to get the standard context menu object (it returns `QMenu`). Modify this menu with custom actions and then return the menu.

The function will be called when the user requests a context menu.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#createStandardContextMenu for more details

EDIT: You can subclass like this

```
class MyTextEdit(QLineEdit):
    def createStandardContextMenu(self, menu):
          #as above, reimplement this method
```

Then you use that class instead of `QLineEdit` when you make your GUI.

Alternatively I've remembered there is a signal called `customContextMenuRequested`. You use this instead like this

```
#assume you have the textbox in a variable called self.my_textbox
self.my_textbox.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.my_textbox.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.generate_context_menu)
```

and then add a method to the class that generates the GUI like:

```
def generate_context_menu(self, location):
    menu = self.my_textbox.createStandardContextMenu()
    # add extra items to the menu

    # show the menu
    menu.popup(self.mapToGlobal(location))
```

Comment: @three_pineapples I am pretty sure the line is supposed to be `self.my_textbox.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.generate_context_menu)`.  I couldn't get it to work regardless, though -- the menu wouldn't pop up -- but overriding contextMenuEvent [as shown in the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#contextMenuEvent) worked.

Comment: @nimble_ninja You're right, that was a mistake!. I've fixed it. It should work with that fix, not sure why it didn't for you. I've done something almost identical (using a lineedit instead of a textedit) [here](https://bitbucket.org/labscript_suite/labscript_utils/src/ee0808eb9205ccda58e0e8362ac3a6323882266f/qtwidgets/analogoutput.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#analogoutput.py-84)